# Kafka connect jdbc source returns 0 record

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Despite the table `news` has more than 65,000,000 records, I don't see any records in Kafka topic.
Connector config:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
        "name": "news_fetcher",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://MY-SERVER/DATABASE",
                "connection.user": "user", 
                "connection.password": "HIDDEN",
                "mode":"bulk",
                "table.whitelist": "news",
                "topic.prefix": "news_"
                }
        }'
```

This message is kept printing in the worker node:

```
[2021-06-06 11:20:29,355] INFO Begin using SQL query: SELECT * FROM `DATABASE`.`news` (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier:164)
[2021-06-06 11:20:31,519] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=news_fetcher-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:424)
[2021-06-06 11:20:31,521] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=news_fetcher-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:441)
```

Before switching to `mysql`, I tested against `sqlite` and everything worked fine. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Logs says it's running the query, and you're not getting errors about the mysql driver missing or some wrong version, so I'd suggest first modifiying the log4j properties to get more DEBUG logs.

Secondly, try limiting the number of rows of each bulk query. Especially since bulk mode is going to continuously upload the data to the topic .

Otherwise, use a different mode value, or switch to Debezium if you want to snapshot a table and get proper CDC Kafka records